# SQL IN Clause - Possibility of Empty Set

Tags: oracle, plsql, in-clause, empty-list

I am trying something like the following

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col IN (SELECT col1 FROM tbl1)
```

However, when `SELECT col1 FROM tbl1` returns no results, I want to display all results from the tbl

Something like this

```
IF(SELECT col1 FROM tbl1)
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col IN (SELECT col1 FROM tbl1)
ELSE
SELECT * FROM tbl
```

Comment: Are you looking for a SQL solution or a PL/SQL solution?  The text of your question sounds like you're looking for a SQL solution but the tags include PL/SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `NOT EXISTS()` statement . Though this solution won't be efficient on large sets of data, so for more efficient method, you can use `PL/SQL`

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE col IN(SELECT col1 FROM tbl1)
   OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl1)
```

Comment: It seems to be the simple solution. Yet I don't understand "this solution won't be efficient on large sets of data" ? Is there other way to make it more efficient?

Comment: Yes, `PL/SQL` doing something similar to what you asked for, but that's another thing. As long as you are properly indexed, this should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate and a little more efficient solution could be:

```
Case when (select Count(*) from tbl1)>0
Then
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col IN (SELECT col1 FROM tbl1)
ELSE
SELECT * FROM tbl
```

Comment: This is  a VALID SQL! It works i have tested it on SQLServer.

Comment: He is using Oracle, not SQL-Server

Comment: I know. Point being its a valid SQL.

Comment: No, this is _Transact-SQL_ (Microsoft's dialect), and thus not a relevant answer to the question. ANSI SQL (or Oracle SQL) does not have an `IF...ELSE` construct. There is a `CASE...WHEN` construct, however, with which you can do similar things.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem creating SQL in JAVA. Where the following solved my problem.

```
query ="SELECT * FROM tbl " 
+ "WHERE (col IN (:PARAMLIST) "
+ "OR (:PARAMLIST) IS NULL)
```

Comment: I couldn't get the idea in here. Firstly this answer not relevant with question. Secondly, when there is `null` inside in clause it will not match with anything anyway.  If your `paramlist` is empty then there will be error due to `in()`. And if it is not empty there will be error again because of `OR 1,2,3 IS NULL`.

Comment: on the other hand, `coalesce` can do the job in this situation. `where (col IN (:PARAMLIST) OR COALESCE(:PARAMLIST) IS NULL)`